# How to divide a list in a substring of size k in all the possible ways

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm

**Consider we have :**

```
size of array = 5
pairs= 3
array= 1 2 3 4 5
```

We need to divide it into int the possible sub list as:

```
[(1,2,3),(4),(5)]

[(1),(2,3,4),(5)]

[(1),(2),(3,4,5)]

[(1,2),(3,4),(5)]

[(1),(2,3),(4,5)]
```

**Suppose if:**

```
size of array = 5
pairs= 2
array= 1 2 3 4 5
```

We need to divide it into int the possible sub list as:

```
[(1,2,3,4),(5)]

[(1),(2,3,4,5)]

[(1,2),(3,4,5)]

[(1,2,3),(4,5)]
```

**The code I have tried:**

```
l1=[1,2,3,4,5]
from itertools import permutations
l2 = permutations(l1)
l3 = [[sum([x[0], x[1]]), sum([x[2], x[3]]),x[4]] for x in l2]
max_arr=[]
for arr in l3:
  max_arr.append(max(arr))
print(min(max_arr))
```

Comment: Is there a specific problem you have achieving this?

Comment: This is for competitive coding (logic building) to be sure , not for the production solution.

Comment: Great... we can help you fix attempts you've tried etc... but at the moment, you're basically asking someone else to do all the work for you... and if someone wanted to do that - they'd be doing this themselves instead of answering on your behalf... Do you know any combinatorics or how to group data... have you looked at Python's `itertools` and things it supplies that might be of use... What level of experience do you have, what do you actually need help with that doesn't sound like you're asking someone to do it all for you?

Comment: The title of the question does not match the stated problem - the _size_ of a _sub list_ is not fixed to _k_.

Comment: Your first example is missing `[(1,2),(3),(4,5)]`, isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To generate all list partitions, you can make a list of `parts-1` ones and `size - parts` zeros. (Note I used `parts` rather `pairs` as more suitable name).

Then generate permutations of this list (for example, with `itertools`), and for every permutation make separation of initial list after indices of 1's. (Note there are `Cnk(size-1, parts-1)` of such permutations).

For example, result `[0,1,1,0]` corresponds to partition `[(1,2),(3),(4,5)]` (divide list after 1st and 2nd items)

This is application of ["stars and bars"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) principle

Comment: corresponds to partition [(1,2),(3),(4,5)] (divide list after 1st and 2nd items),can you explain bit more

Comment: Permutation `[0,1,1,0] ` contains ones at index 1 and at index 2. So we divide source list after index 1 and after index 2.

Answer (score 1):

MBo's good solution may be improved a little by generating combinations of list splitting indexes instead of permutations of separation flags. Then if we're lazy we can pass those indexes directly to [`numpy.split`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.split.html).

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
import itertools
import numpy
parts = 3
for comb in itertools.combinations(range(1, len(l)), parts-1):
    print(numpy.split(l, comb))
```